# Html select fails to drop down in simple case in Firefox, Safari and Chrome. IE OK

Tags: html, select

The "select" in the following html works in IE9.0 but fails to drop-down when clicked in Firefox 10.0, Safari 5.1.7 and Chrome 26.0.  Why?

I'm facing the problem in a more complex web page and have spent some time isolating it down to this simple case.  All the remaining elements and styling appear to need to be present for the problem to occur.

```
<h1>A</h1>
<div style="margin-top: 3px; float: right;">
   <select>
      <option value="1">B</option>
      <option value="2">C</option>
   </select> 
</div>
<div style="position: relative;">
   D
</div>
```

Comment: Removing the style from the first div fixes it: http://jsfiddle.net/Qgtfx/ -- Not sure why though, someone with CSS magic can help here :)

Comment: Your relatively positioned D element is on top of your select box. You can select it if you click at the bottom of it. Try setting the select to have a z-index higher than the relatively positioned div, or changing the width of the div

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle link, tymeJV, never used that before.  Unfortunately, I need those bits of styling in the real-world page. No doubt I'll find a work-around, but I'm fascinated to know why this happens, and it'll help with the fix.

Comment: @EyeNine Inspect your page sir. You will see the div with "D" is on top of your select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer. Your relatively positioned D element is on top of your select box. You can select it if you click at the bottom of it. Try setting the select to have a z-index higher than the relatively positioned div, or changing the width of the div.

A solution:

```
<h1>A</h1>
<div style="margin-top: 3px; float: right;">
   <select>
      <option value="1">B</option>
      <option value="2">C</option>
   </select> 
</div>
<div style="position: relative; width:50px;">
   D
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @itsstephyoutrick, that makes sense - giving the second div a z-index of -1 works.  Removing the relative positioning of the second div also works and is what I've actually done to fix the real page, simply because it has fewer repercussions there.  Although overlapping was certainly a factor (proof: when the second div only partially overlaps the first, the exposed part of the drop-down will work), a static second div still overlaps the first and yet does not stop the drop-down being clicked.  It's fixed, so perhaps I should move on!